# Switch docker image in Azure appservice

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

going through tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

Is it possible to switch docker image on already running appservice?

Comment: what do you mean by that? you want to enable staging?

Comment: this tutorial show how to create  app service web app with custom docker image
but I already have one, and cant recreate it, and want to change   docker image in in without recreating

Answer (score 4):

using this command:

```
az webapp config container set --name <app-name> --resource-group myResourceGroup --docker-custom-image-name <azure-container-registry-name>.azurecr.io/mydockerimage:v1.0.0 --docker-registry-server-url https://<azure-container-registry-name>.azurecr.io --docker-registry-server-user <registry-username> --docker-registry-server-password <password>
```

[az webapp config container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-container-set)

Answer (score 4):

You should go on deployment center.

[image: Deployment center]

Comment: When I change the docker image tag, and hit "save"...the panel goes no further.  It does not acknowledge that the change was made, nor does it give an error.  It simply "sits there".  If I leave the page and come back, it shows the change was never acknowledged.

Comment: We have to wait the end of the process. If you look at the right top of your screen, you can see the status of the process. You should never leave the page before success.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no-longer available in the Deployment Center in the Azure Portal.