# "Container Settings" section missing from Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-appservice, azure-container-registry

I just noticed in my app services on azure, there is no longer a "Container Settings" link.  Does anyone know where we are supposed to configure the container image, etc. now?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57241655/2698119

Answer (score 5):

It's now part of the `Deployment center` blade:

[image]

However, if you're also deploying your webapp via an Azure pipeline, that information can be overridden with the pipeline information, which can hide the container settings.

I've opened a issue on Github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/86094

Comment: This answer no longer appears to be accurate true for linux C# app services

Answer (score 1):

While deploying the app service you will be having an option to deploy it on container [image]

And then you need to fill the details(Docker/container registry) and deploy your app. once you deploy you can see the details in configuration options under settings tab.

[image]

Comment: There used to be a container blade with those settings for already deployed apps, and that has now disappeared. I don't want to redeploy my app just to change the docker image.

Comment: @Métoule did you resolve this? I have a non docker deployed webapp and I don't require a container for web logs.

Comment: @rollsch the logs in the deployment center blade are those of the container (mostly to debug when the container fails). If you don't use docker containers, those logs are of no use to you. If you want to see the web logs, you should use application insights.